# Php forking and memory sharing drive me nuts

Tags: php, fork, pcntl

I have passed hours and days to find why `php` share the memory between my forked children and I figured that if the parent set a var in a function before forking then the function will always return the same result in the children :~

```
new mytest;
class mytest{
    var $t = 'Parent';
    public function __construct(){              
        //$this->runChildProcess($i);       

        $pidsCount = 0;
        for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) { 
            $pids[$pidsCount] = pcntl_fork();
            if($pids[$pidsCount]) {
                $this->t = 'Parent';
                // i am the parent
                $pidsCount++;
            }
            else {
                $this->t = 'Enfant';
                // i am the child
                $this->runChildProcess($i);
                exit();
            }
        }
        for($i = 0; $i < $pidsCount; $i++) {
            pcntl_waitpid($pids[$i], $status, WUNTRACED);
        }
    }

    function runChildProcess($i) {
        $a = rand(0,100)."\n";
        echo $this->t.' : '.$a;
    }   
}
```

If you run this sample it'll be just fine, the children will output different numbers. 
But if you un-comment the first **`$this->runChildProcess($i);`** then you'll see that all the children will return the same result (the first one calculated by a children)

I don't know how to deal with that :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is anything to do with memory sharing.  You're just seeing the behaviour of `rand`.

With that line commented out, each child calls `rand` for the first time, so each gets seeded independently.

With that line uncommented, then `rand` is seeded *before* any of the children are forked.  So they all see the same seed.